# Queue Task Threading

Tags: c#, winforms, queue

i have a method that loads large amount of data in every path .

```
static void Execute()
{
    foreach (var path in paths)
    {
        loadData(path);
    }
}

private static Task _loadTask;
private static Dictionary<string, BarClass> _myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, BarClass>();

static void loadData()
{
      var myCollections = GetCollections.Collections;
     _loadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew((o) =>
     {
        foreach (var item in myCollections)
        {
             // Data Manipulation Goes Here
             ProcessConcat(_myDictionary, item.Value);
        }
     }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}

static void ProcessConcat(Dictionary<string, BarClass> _myDictionary, string key, BarClass value)
{
     if (!_myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
          _myDictionary.Add(key, value)

}
```

problem was since im using collection, im always getting an exception .
now my Question was: How can i implement Queue and Dequeue? :

i need to finish loading first data1, then after it loads data1 it will load the next Data ...

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: item key already added ... null exception... colletion was modified @P.K

Comment: What do you mean with "loading data". Do you mean "retrieving it from the collection / dictionary" or "first the first thread has to load the data, the mainthread has to retrieve it, and then the second thread can load the second data."?

Comment: Why do you use a dictionary? Do you want to retrieve the data by a key?

Comment: Are you calling `loadData` multiple times?

Comment: check the answer and dont forget to mark accepted if you got information you wnat

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of ConcurrentDisctionary to avoid problem in multithreading

Example :

```
class Program
{
    static ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> _concurrent =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

    static void Main()
    {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(A));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(A));
    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    thread1.Join();
    thread2.Join();
    Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}", _concurrent.Values.Average());
    }

    static void A()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        _concurrent.TryAdd(i.ToString(), i);
    }
    }
}
```

find Example source and documentation at: http://www.dotnetperls.com/concurrentdictionary

---

I dont know but in your code to avoid error you need to use lock to make collection thread safe , like as below

```
private readonly Object lockobj = new Object();

static void ProcessConcat(Dictionary<string, BarClass> _myDictionary, string key, BarClass value)
{
    lock(lockobj)
    {
     if (!_myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
          _myDictionary.Add(key, value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a dictionary, use a concurrent queue: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

This queue is thread-safe, your can push a processed item in and retrieve it from another (the main?) thread.